# Play media in WPF from https url

Tags: wpf, mediaelement, mediastream

I am trying to play a video from azure blob storage. While playing it with wpf media element it is giving Exception:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in PresentationCore.dll An unhandled 
exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll Object 
reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

because `url` is `Https`.

I check it with `http` its working fine.

Code

```
<MediaElement Source="https://************MEDIA FROM API******" LoadedBehavior="Manual" x:Name="mePlayer" Visibility="Hidden"> 
    <MediaElement.ContextMenu>
          <ContextMenu />
    </MediaElement.ContextMenu>     
    <MediaElement.DataContext>
         <Properties:Resources/>
    </MediaElement.DataContext>
</MediaElement>
```

when trying to play from code behind

```
mePlayer.Play();
```

it is giving Exception

Comment: Can you also add the code?

Comment: Code  <MediaElement Source="https://************MEDIA FROM API******" LoadedBehavior="Manual" x:Name="mePlayer" Visibility="Hidden" >
            <MediaElement.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu/>
            </MediaElement.ContextMenu>
            <MediaElement.DataContext>
                <Properties:Resources/>
            </MediaElement.DataContext>
        </MediaElement>                                                                                                                     when trying to play from code behind "mePlayer. Play();" it is giving  Exception